# Из TreeViewItem получить текущий элемент

Tags: wpf

Имеется DataTriger для TreeViewItem, который биндится к самому элементу и использует конвертер. В итоге в конвертере для каждого элемента дерева я получаю 
 TreeViewItem. Как мне из оболочки TreeViewItem получить реальный элемент?
Дерево в качестве источника данных использует иерархическую структуру Базового типа (базовый тип для всех элементов дерева), но от базового типа много наследников и мне нужно получать каждый объект дерева в конвертере и выполнять форматирование его отображения в зависимости от типа.

```
        <Style x:Key="TreeItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">

        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource IsActiveNodeConverter}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
```

Заранее всем спасибо за участие!!

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил. Все логично через DataContext получают сами данные скрытые за ItemControl

```
          public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
           var item = (TreeViewItem)value;
           var dataContext = item.DataContext;

          return (dataContext is IActiveLevel);
      }
```